# HTML5 Search Input magnifying glass override?

Tags: html, search, input

I am using an HTML5 search input on my site and in some browsers the magnifying glass is being rendered(Safari/Chrome) and in others it's not (Firefox/IE). How can I override the default magnifying glass icon so I can just code a custom search icon in for every browser?

Switching the input type to text won't work because I want the user to be able to click enter after entering their search.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reset webkit styling:

```
input[type=search] {
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
}
```

To also hide the "Clear" button:

```
::-webkit-search-cancel-button { display: none; }
```

**EDIT**

Some (bad) documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html

You have to scroll down/search for "-webkit-appearance"

Answer (score 0):

```
input {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

or if you want to be more specific

```
input[type="search"] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```